# Wordpress query posts change category with ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a blog for myself and I have made a custom `page-template.php`.
I'm using the Wordpress `query_posts` loop like this:

Well, I got a template called `page-video.php` and I'm using this query!

```
<?php query_posts("cat=65"); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="left-container-video"<?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <header class="video-header">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3></a>
        </header>

             <div class="video-container">
                 <iframe src="<?php the_field("link"); ?>" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div><!-- end vid container -->

     </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2>Sidan hittades inte</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Is there a way to change the `cat=65` value to something else with [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)?

I want to use same template on different Wordpress pages but I want to show different categories.

Comment: Hi! I can't understand your question. Can you be more specific. What you want? What did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, You can do lot of things for that. If I am in your seat i will do like this.

Here is the code. In this I used category slug you can use the id also.

In your `function.php` file add this

```
/*------------------------------------------*/
/**  [media] shortcode function - by Yesh  **/
/*------------------------------------------*/
function mediaShortcode($atts) {
  //Extract Shotcode from the pages and posts
  extract(shortcode_atts(array('slug' => 'default'), $atts));
  global $post;
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category_name' => $atts['slug'], 'orderby'  => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC');
  //print_r($args);
  $posts = get_posts( $args );
  //print_r($posts);
  $html="";
  foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $html.='<article class="left-container-video">';
      $html.='<header class="video-header">';
        $html.='<a href="'.$post->guid.'"><h1>'.$post->post_title.'<h1></a>';
      $html.='</header>';
      $html.='<div class="video-container">';
        $html.=$post->post_content;
      $html.='</div><!-- end vid container -->';
    $html.='</article>';
    //$html.=do_shortcode($post->post_content);
  }
return $html;
}
add_shortcode('media', 'mediaShortcode');
```

in your `template.php`

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Media page Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="wrapper-small">
    <div style="" id="media-page">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- <div class="navigation">
            <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
            <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
        </div> -->
    <?php else : ?>
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and now, as my function. I have to add in the page `[media slug="video-category"]`.
Select page template as `Media Page template. Then`publish`. If you want to show more category posts. Just add after the first line your next category slug.`[media slug="video-gallery]`.

This will show the rest of posts in your gallery. You have to select the theme only. You can use this in any page.

For more information refer these articles.

- http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/06/how-to-create-your-own-wordpress-shortcodes/
- http://www.wpsquared.com/wordpress-shortcodes-get-started-today/

If you need my help. Please find me any of social network by searching `yeshansachithak`.

Comment: Thanks! I'v messed up my while loop. Can you post it for me?

Comment: @Welletoraptus I already edit the answer. Please do customize as your wish.

Comment: @Welletoraptus as per our discuss lats night. I added new code. Use this and put it on that test page. and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `include` a PHP file in each of your custom templates:

`partial-include.php`:

```
<?php query_posts("cat=" . $category_id); // category is not hardcoded ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <article class="left-container-video"<?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <header class="video-header">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3></a>
        </header>
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe src="<?php the_field("link"); ?>" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div><!-- end vid container -->
    </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <h2>Sidan hittades inte</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Then in each of your template files:

`custom-template-1.php`:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Page 1
*/
get_header();
?>

    // ....

    <?php
        $category_id = 123;
        include('partial-include.php');
    ?>

    // ....

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You can repeat this for each of the pages that need the functionality.

If you need to integrate this with custom fields from Advanced Custom Fields, you can change the value of `$category_id` by doing the following in your `custom-template-1.php` file:

```
<?php
    $category_id = get_field('category_id'); // example
    include('partial-include.php');
?>
```